# Delete properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
let array = [{   firstName: "John",   lastName : "Doe",   id:5566, weight: 70 },{   firstName: "Francis",   lastName : "Max",   id:5567, weight: 85 }];
```

How to remove the properties "lastName" and "weight" for all my objects in the array?

Comment: Use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), with a loop, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with Object Destructuring and rest syntax:

```js
let data = [
  {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", id:5566, weight: 70 },
  {firstName: "Francis", lastName: "Max", id:5567, weight: 85 }
];

let result = data.map(({ lastName, weight, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

```
array = array.map(person => ({ firstName: person.firstName, id: person.id }))
```

A little rusty with map, that should be close

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   array[i] = {
       id: array[i].id,
       firstName: array[i].firstName
   }
}
```

Basically, you replace every object in the array with a new object that only contains the desired properties.